# MySQL JOIN behind the scenes

Tags: mysql, join

I remember reading somewhere / being told / inventing a rumor (^_^) that the two following queries are the same behind the scenes in MySQL servers:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
JOIN b
ON a.id = b.id
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM a, b
WHERE a.id = b.id
```

Is it true? If so, is one better than the alternate in other terms? (such as parsing efficiency or standard compliance)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Performance of inner join compared to cross join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670980/performance-of-inner-join-compared-to-cross-join)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL left join vs multiple tables on FROM line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894490/sql-left-join-vs-multiple-tables-on-from-line)

Comment: oops... should have spent more time searching :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in fact true. The first query is according the SQL-89 standard and the second is according to SQL-92.

The SQL-92 standard introduced `INNER JOIN .. ON` and `OUTER JOIN .. ON` in order to replace the more complex(?) syntax of SQL-89.

An outer join in SQL-89 would be:

```
SELECT ...
FROM t1, t2
WHERE t1.id *= t2.id
```

where in SQL-92 it would be

```
FROM t1 OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

I did prefer SQL-89 over SQL-92 for a long while, but I think SQL Server 2008 compability removed the support for SQL-89 join syntax.

Answer (score 0):

yep, these are identical. But it's not something specific to Mysql - it's just a different joining styles. The one you wrote on top is newer and preffered one