# Updating only the rows matched by field value from CROSS JOIN of 2 tables (SQL)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Here's what needs to be done:
Match 2 fields from different tables in SQL Server( done ), update fields in table1 where table1.field1 = table2.field2 (problem, it just updates all the records in the table)

Here's what I have , where tempTableName is a table imported to SQL Server for the purpose of the query:

`"UPDATE Table1 SET Table1.fieldN ='" + DateTime.Now.DayOfYear + "' FROM " + tempTableName + " CROSS JOIN Table1  WHERE (" + tempTableName + ".fieldX = Table1.fieldY)"`

Here's what I've figured out:

everything after the `FROM` is useless as far as actual functionality is concerned, it runs the query but the results are not "linked" in any way to the actual `UPDATE` statement

To sum up :

The query I've figured out updates all records in table1, I need the query to update only the rows matched by the query after `FROM`

PS. Forgive me if this seems trivial and that I haven't done research but the fact of the matter is that 2 weeks ago I'd never even heard of SQL and have relied heavily on SO for direction and advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `CROSS JOIN` should be an `INNER JOIN` instead.

```
"UPDATE t1
    SET fieldN ='" + DateTime.Now.DayOfYear + "' 
    FROM " + tempTableName + " t2 INNER JOIN Table1 t1 ON t1.fieldy = t2.fieldx"
```

Comment: thanks again, whats up with this though ? [Inner Join vs Cross Join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670980/performance-of-inner-join-compared-to-cross-join)

Comment: The example you cite is for a `SELECT` statement. I don't believe that behavior translates to `UPDATE` statements. In any case, explicit `INNER JOIN` is the preferable way to go for either case.