# Table inner join or selecting mutiple tables

Tags: mysql, inner-join

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [INNER JOIN ON vs WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause)

**INNER JOIN:**

---

```
SELECT *
FROM PETS
INNER JOIN OWNER ON PETS.OWNER_ID = 1
AND OWNER.ID = 1
```

---

**MULTIPLE TABLE SELECT:**

---

```
SELECT *
FROM PETS, OWNER
WHERE PETS.OWNER_ID = 1
AND OWNER.ID = 1
```

---

- Is one better than the other?
- Faster than the other?

They seem to produce exactly the same results.

- Is there any difference at all?

*I am trying to learn the best methods. In using the join, I noticed that the exact same thing can be achieved with the multiple table call*

Comment: Is this code causing performance problems, or just curiosity?

Comment: No performance problems.... Yet. I am trying to learn the best methods. In using the join, I noticed that the exact same thing can be achieved with the multiple table call.

Comment: I read this "The second syntax has the unwanted possibility of a cross join: you can add tables to the FROM part without corresponding WHERE clause. This is considered harmful." Here>>> http://sqldatabases.deveronline.com/2012/24/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins.html If any one can ad the explanation as to how this is "considered harmful" part, that could be helpful to this question. But I still can't find any substantiating info on the deprecation of any syntax.

Answer (score 0):

read this answer about the difference between a cross join and an inner join [Performance of inner join compared to cross join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670980/performance-of-inner-join-compared-to-cross-join)