# JPA join by id not entity

Tags: jpa, join, criteria-api

I have created an query with criteria api that retrieves an entity by another linked entity:

```
public List<Booking> getBookingsByUser(User user) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Booking> createQuery = cb.createQuery(Booking.class);
    Root<Booking> booking = createQuery.from(Booking.class);
    Join<Booking, UsersProjects> join = booking.join(Booking_.userProject, JoinType.INNER);
    createQuery.where(cb.equal(join.get(UsersProjects_.user), user));
    createQuery.select(booking);
    return em.createQuery(createQuery).getResultList();
}
```

This is working fine. But how to rewrite this to find entities by userId (Long)?
Metamodel of User has User_.id (SingularAttribute).

User is also an Entity. And a "UsersProject" hast exactly one User and one Project.

Comment: add a cross join, and then using a WHERE clause to relate the two entities by whatever attributes they have in common

Comment: Is `User` an Entity? Which relationship is there between `UserProjects` and `User`?

Comment: @NEil how - could you please show as code?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106434/join-unrelated-entities-with-jpa-api-criteria

Comment: it s no real duplicate - but it doesn't matter because there is no accepted answer

Comment: The only answer is the only way you can do it. So have you actually tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one more join clause between `UserProjects` and `User`:

```
Join<Booking, UsersProjects> userProjectsJoin = booking.join(Booking_.userProject, JoinType.INNER);
Join<UsersProjects, User> userJoin = userProjectsJoin.join(UserProjects_.user);
createQuery.where(cb.equal(userJoin.get(User_.id), userId));
```

Comment: i tried it see my edited question - it is not working?! could you check if i di it right?

Comment: Show the relationships, as I asked in my comment to your question, and if it's not working then show what it means: do you get an error? Which error? Or do you get a result set different from what you expected? If yes, log the resulting query and post it. By the way, you code looks right, apart the fact that you are using the variable `projectId` instead of `userId`.

Comment: you saved my day - the problem was indeed fiddling around with userId/projectId :-P.