# CriteriaAPI join entity which is not mapped to root entity

Tags: hibernate, join, criteria-api

I want to prepare a simple SQL query with join using criteriaAPI. Let's assume that I have table PERSON with column ID and PET_ID which refers table PET. In my application I have both Person and PET entity, however PET isn't mapped to an entity - person keeps only pet id as number.

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column("PET_ID")
    private int petId;
}

@Entity
public class Pet {

    @Id
    private int id;

}
```

Those are only examples but it's enough to show what I want to achieve. In Oracle I would write simple query:

```
SELECT _p.id, _pet.id from PERSON _p join PET _pet on _p.pet_id=_pet.id;
```

But I am not able to achieve this using criteriaAPI - I know that if I would have Pet entity mapped in Person class it would be easy, but with below example I already spent much time without finding any solution

Comment: How come there is no link between `Person` and `Pet` entity? If link exists between these two entities then you could use `Join` and achieve the desired results.

Comment: Yes I know, In my real problem two entities are from different buisness domain, our architect doesn't want to mix them.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17106521/599528), perhaps of some help.

Comment: Another option would be to create a database view where you join all tables and use the view as your entity.

Comment: First possibility doesn't help since I finally have to make outer join - it would help if i would need inner. Second one would help that's true but I was wondering if I am able to create query which I wanted to. Anyway thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you cannot do this from `criteria` unless there a reference to `Pet` in `Person`.

However, you can get the desired result using `org.hibernate.Query`. *reply in comment and i'll post the required code for that.*

However, if it's necessary to get the desired result using `Criteria`, then I've posted a temporary Hack which will work in your case.

```
List<Integer> allPetIds = session.createCriteria(Pet.class)
            .setProjection(Projections.property("id"))
            .list();

List<Person> persons = session.createCriteria(Person.class)
            .add(Restrictions.in("petId", allPetIds))
            .list();
```

Comment: Thanks - it's kind of trick however it doesn't solve my problem. I was not precise in my example since I wanted to clearly show idea of thing which I am searching for. In my real problem I want to make left outer join PET and check some condition on joined table, not only Ids therefore I need full entity in my query to cooperate. It seems that only way to achieve that is to link the second entity