# Mysql Query with and without join

Tags: mysql, database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
  `maker` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `model` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`model`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `laptop` (
  `code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `model` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `speed` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `ram` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `hd` double NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `screen` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`code`),
  KEY `FK_Laptop_product` (`model`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

These are the two tables, now I have two queries-

```
SELECT * FROM `product` inner join laptop on product.model = laptop.model
```

and

```
select * from product, laptop where product.model = laptop.model
```

Both the queries gives same result, So is there any difference in two approaches. 
Please provide few good examples

Comment: THis is about inner join compared to cross join, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670980/performance-of-inner-join-compared-to-cross-join

Comment: That's actually the same query, just using two different notations!

Comment: No comment. Both of them are the same.

Comment: Search on Google for implicit v/s explicit join. Performance wise even they should be almost same. While implicit joins are discouraged.

Comment: @almasshaikh From MySQL's POV, they are identical. The EXPLAIN (EXTENDED) would prove this.

Comment: Sorry for duplicate question.