# query show 0 record from two tables have same data on join

Tags: mysql, join

'm filtering records from 2 tables  `users` and `temp_bach_users_registeration` on the base of `email` both have some same emails but in query record is `null` but when i individually search from both they show me records

in `temp_bach_users_registeration` table i import records from `CSV` is there this issue is because of csv ??

**Query:**

```
SELECT
users.email,
temp_bach_users_registeration.email
FROM
users, temp_bach_users_registeration 
WHERE users.email = temp_bach_users_registeration.email
```

users table is `MyISAM` and temp_bach_users_registeration is `InnoDB` storage engine .

**DB Structure of users table :**
[image]
........
[image]

**DB Structure of temp_bach_users_registeration table :**
[image]
..........
[image]

can somebody help me to figure out this issue .

thanks .

Comment: Show some sample data please.

Comment: Do both email columns use the same character set / collation?

Comment: yes both have same character set / collation but storage engines are different.

Comment: @Haseeb - you respond to questions but fail to provide the requested sample data. Without sample data, I doubt you'll get an answer soon.

Comment: Did you try to use LIKE or STRCMP to compare your strings?

Comment: http://dbaspot.com/databases/399510-strange-problem-mysql-string-comparison.html seems to be related. `WHERE STRCMP(users.email,temp_bach_users_registeration.email) = 0` could solve the issue.

Comment: probably during the importation, the email addresses kept the  char " from the begin to the end as field separator

Comment: @Strawberry Well, apparently it is not :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670980/performance-of-inner-join-compared-to-cross-join

Comment: @Strawberry I have to admit, that my mental query optimizer was not working as effectively as the real one ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i got the issue. there is `\r` in end of value of column `emails` in `temp_bach_users_registeration` table but it not shows in phpMyadmin .

i find this by searching again with this query .

```
SELECT *
FROM `temp_bach_users_registeration`
WHERE `email` IN('test@yahoo.com\r')
LIMIT 0, 1000
```

and got the records.

Comment: That's rather random. :-(

Answer (score 0):

try in this way

```
SELECT
users.email,
temp_bach_users_registeration.email
FROM
users, temp_bach_users_registeration 
WHERE trim(users.email) = trim(temp_bach_users_registeration.email)
```

Comment: same result no record frond . :(

Comment: very very strange... can you post a screenshot of the tables or something like that?
Which kind of ODBC driver are you using or kind of Sql explorer?!
What about email fields? Text or Char?

Comment: both are varchar(100) and collection is utf8_general_ci