# Display partial results when subtracting row values from the same column for different time periods when data may not exist using SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

I have a table, car_data, as follows:

| id | car | date | mileage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | car_4 | 2021-01-05 | 10000 |
| 2 | car_1 | 2021-01-10 | 20 |
| 3 | car_3 | 2021-01-11 | 300000 |
| 4 | car_2 | 2021-01-31 | 1000 |
| 5 | car_3 | 2021-07-31 | 304000 |
| 6 | car_4 | 2021-11-30 | 10500 |
| 7 | car_2 | 2021-12-01 | 2200 |
| 8 | car_1 | 2021-12-31 | 500 |
| 9 | car_2 | 2022-02-02 | 2400 |
| 10 | car_4 | 2022-02-07 | 10900 |
| 11 | car_1 | 2022-02-15 | 530 |

Now I need a MySQL (v 5.7) query that produces the following result:

| car | year_2021_mileage | year_2022_mileage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| car_1 | 480 | 30 |
| car_2 | 1200 | 200 |
| car_3 | 4000 |  |

Note: the solution should include only selected cars (e.g., car_1, car_2, and car_3 but not car_4).

My MySQL (v 5.7) query nearly works, except for car_3.  car_3 only operated in 2021.  It did not operate in 2022.  However, the query excludes car_3 from the results, even for 2021.

Note: data is added over time so the auto-incrementing id may be used to find earliest or latest entries in the query.

Note: the actual data has lots of cars with mileage reporting on many days (e.g., not just start/end of year).  The desired solution should be able to filter the cars to a subset of all cars.

I derived my approach from the example and solution shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26817139/how-can-i-subtract-two-rows-values-within-same-column-using-sql-query) to substract values from different rows within the same column.

Explanation of my strategy:

- t1 represents most recent mileage from 2022
- t2 represents mileage from end of 2021
- t3 represents mileage from start of 2021
- Joining approach for t2 and t3 effectively create a cross join with t1 (I'm using this approach because my query is generated using Python SQLAlchemy ORM package which doesn't support cross join method but this approach seems to work)
- The subquery joins restrict the t1, t2, t3 results to the appropriate date for each car

```
    SELECT t1.car,
       t2.mileage - t3.mileage AS year_2021_mileage,
       t1.mileage - t2.mileage AS year_2022_mileage

    FROM   car_data t1
       JOIN car_data t2
         ON t1.id IS NOT NULL
       JOIN car_data t3
         ON t1.id IS NOT NULL

       JOIN (SELECT Max(anon.id) AS recent_id
             FROM   car_data AS anon
             WHERE  anon.car = 'car_1'
                    AND anon.date >= '2022-01-01'
                     OR anon.car = 'car_2'
                        AND anon.date >= '2022-01-01'
                     OR anon.car = 'car_3'
                       AND anon.date >= '2022-01-01'
             GROUP  BY anon.car) AS anon_1
         ON anon_1.recent_id = t1.id

       JOIN (SELECT Max(anon.id) AS end_of_year_id
             FROM   car_data AS anon
             WHERE  anon.car = 'car_1'
                    AND anon.date <= '2021-12-31'
                     OR anon.car = 'car_2'
                        AND anon.date <= '2021-12-31'
                     OR anon.car = 'car_3'
                        AND anon.date <= '2021-12-31'
             GROUP  BY anon.car) AS anon_2
         ON anon_2.end_of_year_id = t2.id

       JOIN (SELECT Min(anon.id) AS start_of_last_year_id
             FROM   car_data AS anon
             WHERE  anon.car = 'car_1'
                    AND anon.date >= '2021-01-01'
                     OR anon.car = 'car_2'
                        AND anon.date >= '2021-01-01'
                     OR anon.car = 'car_3'
                        AND anon.date >= '2021-01-01'
             GROUP  BY anon.car) AS anon_3
         ON anon_3.start_of_last_year_id = t3.id

    WHERE  t1.car = t2.car
       AND t1.car = t3.car
```

Please see the fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gwHVT1Uh4nzr9GtfQse764/2) which can be used to test solutions.

Update: I received the following solution which is compatible with MySQL v8.0.  It uses CTE and LAG which are not supported in MySQL v5.7.  I'm including it because I like the strategy of using the maximum and minimum mileage for each year.  It may serve as good starting point for a solution that works on MySQL v5.7.  There's a working fiddle of this solution (for MySQL v8.0) at this [link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jQRNfJgJfh5eeKMpY1E5xk/1)

```
  with cte1 as (
   -- CTE1 - get every combination of car and year to ensure no gaps
   select D1.car, year(D2.date) year
    from car_data D1
    cross join car_data D2
    group by D1.car, year(D2.date)
),
cte2 as (
    -- CTE2 - join on the actual data and get the mileage at the start and end of the year
    select C.car, year, min(mileage) start, max(mileage) end
    from cte1 C
    left join car_data D on D.car = C.car and year(D.date) = C.year
    group by C.car, year
),
cte3 as (
    -- CTE3 use lag to get the mileage at the end of last year as the start data for this year where it exists
    select car, year
      , lag (end,1,start) over (partition by car order by car, year) start
      , end
    from cte2
)

select car
  , sum(case when year = 2021 then end-start else null end) 2021_year_mileage
  , sum(case when year = 2022 then end-start else null end) 2022_year_mileage
from cte3
where car='car_1' or car='car_2' or car='car_3'
group by car
order by car;
```

Comment: I also had an issue with the fiddle on http://sqlfiddle.com/.  The new fiddle is on https://www.db-fiddle.com/.  Hopefully that works.  Also, I'm using MySQL version 5.7.