# sql difference in same column from bottom to top value

Tags: mysql, sql

table :

| a |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 4 |
| 8 |
| 9 |

desired output

| a |
| --- |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 1 |

Comment: 'LAG(expr [, N[, default]]) [null_treatment] over_clause

Returns the value of expr from the row that lags (precedes) the current row ' - are you aware of this function and do you have version 8x

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lead` to get the value of `a` from the next row (ordered by `a`):

```
select * from 
(select lead(a) over(order by a) - a as a
from table_name) t
where a is not null;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=35f8f4e736f6b1da7eb1d006a0d51bd8)

Answer (score 0):

I am using the [How can I subtract two row's values within same column using sql query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26817139/how-can-i-subtract-two-rows-values-within-same-column-using-sql-query)
logic.

1. First we will give row number to your table

   ```
   Select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by a) as rn, a
    From tb1
   ```

   **Output:**

[image]

2. We will create a temp table where the first row will be missing and the row number will adjust like that:

   ```
   Select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by a) as rn, cte.a
   From cte
   Where cte.rn != 1
   ```

**Output:**

[image]

3. Finally will just join the table using the rn and substruct the value

   ```
   With cte as(
     Select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by a) as rn, cte.a
     From cte
     Where cte.rn != 1
   )
   cte_2 as(
     Select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by a) as rn, cte.a
     From cte
     Where cte.rn != 1
    )
     Select ABS(cte.a - cte_2.a) as sub
     From cte join cte_2
     on cte.rn = cte_2.rn
   ```

**Output**
[image]