# Hibernate Automatically Prevent Cross Joins without rewriting large query?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

Suppose I have a Hibernate-generated large query that comes out with CROSS JOINs which is impacting performance:

```
SELECT studyt0_.abbreviation                                AS col_0_0_,
       userst2_.user_name                                   AS col_1_0_,
       recallst3_.id                                        AS col_2_0_,
       recallst3_.recall_date                               AS col_3_0_,
       recallst3_.created_date                              AS col_4_0_,
       (SELECT lookupt8_.description
        FROM   PUBLIC.answers_t answerst5_
               CROSS JOIN PUBLIC.activity_questions_t activityqu6_
               CROSS JOIN PUBLIC.activities_t activities7_
               CROSS JOIN PUBLIC.lookup_t lookupt8_
        WHERE  lookupt8_.id = activities7_.activity_category_id
               AND activities7_.id = activityqu6_.activity_id
               AND activityqu6_.id = answerst5_.activity_question_id
               AND activityqu6_.question_id = 1
               AND answerst5_.event_id = eventst4_.id)      AS col_5_0_,
       (SELECT activities11_.activity_title
        FROM   PUBLIC.answers_t answerst9_
               CROSS JOIN PUBLIC.activity_questions_t activityqu10_
               CROSS JOIN PUBLIC.activities_t activities11_
        etc
```

This is due to **implicit joins** we have in our HQL, as I understand.

```
(select l.description from AnswersT ans, ActivityQuestionsT aq, ActivitiesT a, LookupT l " + 
            "where l.id=a.lookupT.id and a.id=aq.activitiesT.id and aq.id=ans.activityQuestionsT.id and aq.questionsT.id=1 and ans.eventsT.id=e.id) as category, " +
```

Question:
Is there a way to quickly get rid of the CROSS JOINs and replace them with INNER JOINs without rewriting the entire query, which is very large? Is there a config workaround of some kind?

Comment: If you want inner joins then by definition you need to provide the `ON` clauses. If you're asking whether Hibernate can 'guess' them for you, then the answer is that it's not that powerful, I'm afraid

Comment: Also, did you measure the actual performance penalty of using cross join vs inner joins in your query? See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670980/performance-of-inner-join-compared-to-cross-join) for a discussion on cross join performance. In essence, decent query optimizers don't care which join syntax you use

Comment: Yes you're right. After removing the cross joins the performance didn't improve.

Answer (score 1):

I see here 2  things that can be optimized.

1) The approach `(select A from ...) as nameA, (select B from ...) as nameB, ...`
leads to a huge cross join: Every value in the 1st column will be combined with every value in the 2nd column etc. To me it looks like a bug. Normally there should be only one *from* clause, something like `select A as nameA, select B as nameB, ... from ...`.

2) Independent on this, check your *where* clause. The current condition

```
where l.id=a.lookupT.id and a.id=aq.activitiesT.id and aq.id=ans.activityQuestionsT.id
  and aq.questionsT.id=1 and ans.eventsT.id=e.id
```

can be replaced with a simpler one:

```
where ans.activityQuestionsT.questionsT.id = 1
```

Comment: It has to be like that because the nested `(select A from..)` are for separate **columns**. The report needs to present some data as columns. That's why there are Inner selects.

Comment: This would be a strange report because it will combine all possible values. If `select` for the first column finds 2 values A and B, and if `select` for the 2nd colum finds 3 values 1000, 2000 and 5000, then your report will contain 6 rows (not 2, not 3): One row `A   1000`, next row `A   2000`, then `A   5000`, then `B   1000`, 'B   2000', `B   5000`. Another example: If you have 6 columns and each has 10 values, your report will contain 10 x 10 x 10 x 10 x 10 x 10 = 1 000 000 rows. Are you sure that you report should contain all possible independent combinations of all possible values?